# Can I get user's profile picture reactions without user_photos permission?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I do following request

```
FB.api("/me/picture", {type: 'large'}, function(response){ 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); 
});
```

I get this response:

```
{"height":200,"is_silhouette":false,"url":"SOME_URL","width":200}
```

I'm testing this on my own profile and I haven't granted **user_photos** permission (with **user_photos** we can easily get albums and reactions). So is there any other allowed way to get reactions on profile picture? Like getting Photo ID of this picture so that we can get other info?

I guess it might be possible because likes are public (no?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture endpoint does not offer any likes or reactions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/user/picture

It is different to regular photos and basically just a way to show a picture of the user in your App.